# Configure firewall and proxy server or just firewall for outbound connections

Tags: firewall, proxy, https

I'm actually a software developer and I am working on a web application which uses Recaptcha. I am using Asp.Net C# in a web form application.

I am having an issue with the server trying to verify the Recaptcha with Google's API.

We plan on using it on an https site and my question is do we need to create exceptions in the firewall or the proxy server or both?

I currently get the error: `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

I have looked for solutions and most say to allow outbound connections. But do I do this on the firewall only?

We currently have a firewall and a proxy server.

On one of the development machines I created a new outbound rule in the windows firewall to allow outbound connections to port 443 (https).  I still get the same error.

Does the proxy server need to be configured as well?

Sorry if this is not the correct place for the question, I was going to post it on the normal stack overflow site, but the question was more about server setup than programming.

Comment: Hi. What port does the proxy use?

Comment: @EamonnTravers - I am not sure, but I can find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We plan on using it on an https site and my question is do we need to create exceptions in the firewall or the proxy server or both?

Usually the proxy will be standing behind the firewall (fw), or put it another way the fw is between the proxy & the INET. The fw will allow the proxy to connect to port 443, 80 etc on any INET servers. The servers are behind the proxy, so put it another way, the servers connect with the proxy & not with the INET. So you need to allow the proxy to connect over the fw with the INET.

> I have looked for solutions and most say to allow outbound connections. But do I do this on the firewall only?

Yes outbound traffic is allowed on the firewall.

> Does the proxy server need to be configured as well?

Yes, the proxy will need to know which servers can connect to the INET.

This a ll very general. I would need to know more about the setup. But I hope it was helpful anyway.

Comment: Hey, your answer was very helpful.  We took a look at the traffic from the firewall and it showed us that there was an http connection being made even though we were using an https connection. Turns out the issue was in the software (incorrect verification url). Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.